# When mimicing a user click to invoke a callback, the root property CallbackObject is not updated?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-figure

I have a MATLAB m-file (mainGUI.m) which produces a GUI: a figure that contains some uicontrol objects (pushbuttons, menus, etc), each with a specific callback function. When I click around in the GUI, everything works fine, it does exactly what it is supposed to.

Now, I have another m-file (external.m) which, when executed, calls the m-file above, and mimics one of the callbacks (myCallbackfcn.m), as if the user was actually pushing a button. Below is the relevant pieces of code that executes inside external.m:

```
% Launch the GUI
mainGUI();

% Obtain the handles-structure, and the handle to the pushbutton
handles = guidata(findall(0,'type','figure')); 
hObject = handles.myPushButton;

% Execute the callback
myCallbackfcn(hObject,[]);
```

This also works fine - inside the myCallbackfcn, the hObject is indeed the correct handle, I can get access to the entire GUI handle structure, and so on... But there is one flaw, which is crucial to the purpose of my code. The root property CallbackObject is empty! Whereas, it should be the handle to the hObject, which it is when I initiate the callback manually by clicking on the pushbutton.

Does anyone have an idea of why CallbackObject is not updated? It is read-only, so I can't change it by force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CallbackObject` of the root object is empty because you are not executing the callback from an actual GUI event. The `CallbackObject` is automatically populated by MATLAB when you interact with a GUI widget.

Within your callback, rather than relying on the `CallbackObject` (or `gcbo`), you can get the object *directly* from your `handles` struct.

```
myCallbackfcn(hObject, [], handles)

function myCallbackfcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    callbackObject = handles.myPushButton;

    % Or more simply
    callbackObject = hObject;

    % Do stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Suever! The reason that I would like to have the CallbackObject-property updated is because I already have thousands of lines of code, and hundereds of callback functions, that rely on gcbo not being empty. It works as long as I run the GUI manually, but now that I want to run it remotely, I also run into problems.. So if there is no easy way of tricking MATLAB (into changing the CallbackObject property), I will have to go over all my previous codes.. though, as you point out, the changes are quite small.

Comment: @ibbore Yea there is no way to set either `gcbo` or `CallbackObject` unfortunately. You *could* write your own function named `gcbo` which could return the object of your choosing and then all your other functions would automatically call this instead of the built-in version.

Comment: That's an idea.. though a little risky (in case one actually needs the true gcbo later) This project is growing bigger and bigger, and one day I will have to hand it off to someone, so for that reason I suppose I better go over my functions and replace the gcbo:s... Thanks a lot for your comments, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @ibbore Yes. You could always use `builtin('gcbo')` but in general that is an error-prone option. If this answer helped you, consider marking it as a solution (even though admittedly it isn't quite what you wanted to hear :/)